# Facebook Login Permission for testing the app before submitting for review?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, facebook-permissions

I am trying to get some login permission from the user in my facebook app. Facebook asks the developer to send their app for review before giving any extra permissions to the developer. For this, it seems that you have to complete the app and it is working so they can test and do whatever they want before giving the developer or the app the extra required login permission!

Currently I am only testing the application and it is not complete, but I need that extra login permission (`manage_pages` to be exact) so I can see what my app would do and how it will work...

But it seems facebook only asks for fully developed apps to be sent for review.

This is all very confusing. and facebook documentations is like has been written by a 2 fingered person who couldn't even be bothered with finishing the whole sentence!

The question that I have is this:

Is there any way I could create an app and get all the login permissions that required to test the app and make it all work before sending it to facebook for review?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Is there any way I could create an app and get all the login permissions that required to test the app and make it all work before sending it to facebook for review?*

It's by **default** only. The developers/admin/testers of the app can test the application even if those are not reviewed by facebook.

The permissions should be **added in your login code**. The permissions wont be asked just like that by adding them in the review details, instead the permissions are added with the login code using the `scope` parameter. Check [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0) for the details. That's straight-forward!

For example-

**JS SDK-**

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
}, {scope: 'manage_pages'});
```

**Manual login flow-**

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
  client_id={app-id}&
  redirect_uri={redirect-uri}&
  auth_type=rerequest&
  scope=manage_pages
```

Just test your app and when its ready submit for the review adding the extra permissions and their details. Hope that helps!

Comment: see, I've already found that "NOt really" straight forward link in google. it doesn't say anything about how to test the app with the required permissions. not trying to be rude but do you work for facebook? because the way you explained it here is exactly like facebook's documentation which is confusing! I still don't know if or how I can get the required login permission in a test mode!

Comment: You read about the `scope` in login flow that I've added in the answer? There ONE AND ONLY ONE way to add permissions in the app, using the `scope` in login code. What facebook says that first we will test your app before you make your appl ive else none of your extra permissions will work. I dont know why are you confused!

Answer (score 5):

I know it's a very late answer, but maybe some one else will has benefit from it.

> Is there any way I could create an app and get all the login
>   permissions that required to test the app and make it all work before
>   sending it to facebook for review?

After a lot of search in Google and Stackoverflow, I found my own answer. The problem was the application on Facebook is **"Live"**, Once I turned toggle off or **"in development"** mode, it allowed me to test the permissions without granted them from Facebook first.

Comment: For me, it was tagged as business app when i removed the tag it working and also definitely you have to be in development mode.

Comment: it helped definitely but i'm having different issues now. who generated app token cannot give permission to ads account with specific business manager which i'm trying to give access to a bms for a adaccounts, pages. though pages works but ad account not :( not upderstanding what's going on. 

here's the error log: 
(#10) You do not have permission to perform this action. This action requires that you can MODIFY_AD_ACCOUNTS for this business account

and also the API i'm using is this. : 
`https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/${businessID}/client_ad_accounts?access_token=${accessToken}`

Comment: Okay, you can make new Stackoverflow question, and may one of the community helps you.